# RecycleView duplicating items

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I have a **RecycleView** in my program that holds a bunch of **DownloadItem** instances, however, recently I found something weird.

If the user keeps adding DownloadItem instances then at some point they will be copied and sometimes they stay and sometimes they disappear.

An example of both the cloned item disappearing and staying: [RecycleView duplicating items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDXZm.jpg)

My Code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ColorProperty
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class DownloadItem(MDCard):
    path = StringProperty()
    url_type = StringProperty("file")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.paused = False
        self.fill_animation = None
        super(DownloadItem, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def pause_resume_download(self):
        if not self.paused:
            self.ids.pause_resume_button.icon = "play"
            if self.fill_animation is not None:
                self.fill_animation.cancel(self.ids.progress_bar)
            self.paused = True
        else:
            self.ids.pause_resume_button.icon = "pause"
            self.fill_animation = Animation(value=100, duration=4)
            self.fill_animation.bind(on_complete=lambda *args: Animation(color=self.theme_cls.accent_color,
                                                                            duration=Example.color_duration)
                                        .start(self.ids.progress_bar))
            self.fill_animation.start(self.ids.progress_bar)
            self.paused = False
        Animation(color=app.pause_color if self.paused else self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                    duration=Example.color_duration).start(self.ids.progress_bar)

    def cancel_download(self):
        if self.fill_animation is not None:
            self.fill_animation.cancel(self.ids.progress_bar)
        Animation(color=app.fail_color,
                duration=Example.color_duration).start(self.ids.progress_bar)

class Example(MDApp):
    fail_color = ColorProperty([255 / 255, 99 / 255, 71 / 255, 1.0])
    pause_color = ColorProperty([240 / 255, 163 / 255, 10 / 255, 1.0])
    success_color = ColorProperty(None)
    color_duration = .15


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global app
        super(Example, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
<TooltipMDLabel@MDLabel+MDTooltip>
<DownloadItem>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 100
    elevation: 20
    border_radius: 5
    radius: [5]
    MDBoxLayout:
        adaptive_height: True
        spacing: 5
        MDIcon:
            icon: root.url_type
            size_hint_x: None
            width: self.texture_size[0]
        TooltipMDLabel:
            text: root.path if len(root.path) <= 30 else root.path[:31] + " ..."
            tooltip_text: f"Path: {root.path} | Type: {root.url_type}"
            tooltip_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_darkest
            tooltip_text_color: app.theme_cls.opposite_bg_darkest
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
    MDSeparator:
    MDBoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        MDProgressBar:
            id: progress_bar
            min: 0
            max: 100
            value: 50
            color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        MDIconButton:
            id: pause_resume_button
            icon: "pause"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            on_release: root.pause_resume_download()
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "close"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            on_release: root.cancel_download()
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 10
    RecycleView:
        id: downloads_list
        viewclass: "DownloadItem"
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, 100
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: 15
            spacing: 15
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Add"
        size_hint_x: 1
        on_release: app.add_item()''')
        self.path = "C:/Users/Family/Downloads/"
        app = self

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return self.kv

    def add_item(self):
        self.kv.ids.downloads_list.data.append({"path": self.path + '/' if self.path[-1] != '/' else self.path,
                                            "url_type": "file"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run()
```

Comment: The intent of a `RecycleView` is to recycle the `viewclass` instances, thus saving time and memory. However, the `RecycleView` only adjusts the properties of the `viewclass` that are provided in the `data`. Any changes that you make to a `viewclass` instance are unknown to the `RecycleView` and will appear for different items when that `viewclass` instance gets recycled. So, the question becomes, are you getting so many `DownloadItems` that you actually need to use `RecycleView`?

Comment: @John Anderson, in my actual program the user can have as many download items as they desire. The reason that I chose to use recycleview is that they can have hundreds or thousands of these items and the amount varies from user to user. In order to consider all possible amounts, for the better reasons I chose to use recycleview

Comment: I would suggest a slight redesign where your `DownloadItem` does not contain a `ProgressBar`, but instead has a download state indicator of some sort with a value that can be specified in the `data`. Something like "Downloadable", "Queued for Download", "Downloading", or "Downloaded".  If you want a `ProgressBar`, that could be created and displayed in a list (not a `RecycleView`). And that list could be limited in size.